# Problems with requests Python 3 retrieving an excel file from a WP site

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

Here's my problem, I am trying to download excel xlsx files from a WP site, if I type

the url I assigned to a variable in my code, called stock, directly in browser, Firefox downloads it perfectly.

I'm trying to do this with Python so I've made a script using requests and then Pandas for processing and manipulation.

However even though the file seems to download it returns an error, I tried using both open and with open as suggested on similar problems I've found here, but in my case it returns an error 'ValueError: Seek of closed file', I attempted several variations to the code, with no result, the outcome was always the error.

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, os
import http.client

http.client.HTTPConnection._http_vsn = 10
http.client.HTTPConnection._http_vsn_str = 'HTTP/1.0'

# Url of the same link I used to manually fetch the file
stock = 'https://filmar.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/Apple-Lot-5-14-21.xlsx'

resp = requests.get(stock)  # passed the GET method to the http request with the URL

print("Downloading...") # This works

# When I try to retrieve the file it fails 
with open('Apple-Lot-5-14-21.xlsx', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(resp.content)
    
print('The file has been downloaded') # this is printed

# The error happens when I try to assign the file to the pd.read_excel method in Pandas
apple = pd.read_excel(output)
```

Addendum

After entering the code [resp - object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqtjz.png)provided by @MattDMo, apparently there's a permission problem or something, because upon analysis of the response object, models.response it returned a 404, not found, so either it's a protection or some redirection that takes place on the server, so requests retrieves an empty file.

Comment: You've downloaded the file into memory, but you haven't saved it to disk yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass `output` to `pd.read_excel()`, because when the `with` context manager exits, the reference to the file (`output`) is destroyed. One option here, if you don't *really* need to save the Excel file for anything else, is to pass `resp.content` directly to `read_excel()`. Alternatively, if you want the Excel file for backup or other purposes, create a filename variable like so:

```
xl_file = 'Apple-Lot-5-14-21.xlsx'
```

then use that variable both when you're calling `with open(...` *and* when you're calling `read_excel()`, as that function can take both file names and file-like objects.

As an extra note, I'm not sure why you're using `http.client`, as `requests` doesn't look at any of those values to my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your response! @MattDMo, I have been working with Pandas for a few months, but most of the time they were csv files, not really familiar with the requests library nor the read_excel() pandas method. I thought it was something wrong with the retrieved files because, the file that was downloaded,  had a different weight, instead of 15k it was more like 162 bytes,  so I was trying to figure out if there were some missing parameters, or something else I skipped for my lack of experience. BTW I used http.client because I read a similar case here, that used it, for type http 1.0 reqs.